# Can I relate MFTIME to the real system time?

Tags: streaming, live-streaming, ms-media-foundation

I am writing some code that forwards samples from Windows Media Foundation to live555. While MF uses its 100 ns timestamps, live555 uses "real time" in form of `struct timeval`. I know how to fake the latter from `GetSystemTime()`, but I wonder whether it is possible to derive the "real time" from the MF sample time and the data passed to `IMFClockStateSink::OnClockStart`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Media Foundation also provides a presentation time source based on the system clock.

While this presentation source is providing time stamps based on system clock (presumably using or using shared source with `timeGetTime` but I did not check), this source is not the only option.

So you basically should not make assumptions on correlation between clock time and current system "absolute" time. Time stamps are supposed to only provide relative time increments at 10 MHz rate.

> [If the presentation clock uses some other time source, ...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703153)

Comment: However, I need to generate some kind of absolute time for live555. The question is: how would I do that? My best guess atm would be capturing the `MESessionStarted` event, retrieve the system time in the handler and assuming that the relative time passed as `hnsSystemTime` to `IMFClockStateSink::OnClockStart` is approximately the relative time when `MESessionStarted` was generated. Does that make sense?

Comment: So why don't you save both clock values on session startup and then calculate absolute time as session start absolute time plus media clock difference. I suppose it's what you had in mind - yes, it makes sense.

Comment: That was the idea - the question is whether there is a "better" way to do it (obviously not if I understand you correctly) and whether the `MESessionStarted` event is the right place to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I just understood what you are asking: I cannot save `hnsSystemTime` and the system time in `IMFClockStateSink::OnClockStart`, because if I add audio, I will have two `IMFStreamSink`s which would then remember a different system time.

Comment: You should be able to do this simple math anyway. You have several clocks which run "independently" but in real time. At some point you match them one to another and then you can convert between any given two.

Comment: But assuming I have an `IMFStreamSink` for audio and one for video, I will not be able to get the same system time in `OnClockStart`, because MF needs to call those methods sequentially. I think, I will just try `MESessionStarted` and compute the offset from there ...

Comment: The sinks are different but somehow you still manages them from the higher level code? I suppose they might be sample grabber sinks (your another question), in which case the callbacks anyway lead to your code and you can sync them.

Comment: Atm, I have a `IMFMediaSink` which manages two `IMFStreamSinks` - but I am considering changing that to grabbers. In either case, I need to provide the time externally, tough, because the sink receiving the timer information does not know about the others.